# Prove that f has at least one global minimizer

Tags: limits, functions, optimization, convex-optimization

$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that

$\displaystyle\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$

On a side note: how can a function have more than one global minimizer? Is a global minimizer not, by definition, $f(x^*) \le f(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: Why should $f(x)$ be convex based on this alone?

Comment: What's the global minimizer $x^*$ of $f(x) = 1$?

Comment: You're right. I thought f(x) had to be convex to have a global minimizer. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ is convex. It's not strictly convex, however.

Comment: Another convex function with more than one global minimum: $\max\{|x|-1,0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions you've presented are not enough to prove that $f$ is convex.

**Hint for proving that $f$ has an absolute minimum:**

By definition of the limit, there exists a $\rho > 0$ such that $f(x) > f(0)$ whenever $\|x\| > \rho$.

Note that $f$ must attain a minimum on $\{x:\|x\| \leq \rho\}$.  Why is this also the absolute minimum?

Comment: I would have thought it is an absolute minimum if and only if f(x) is convex. Is this not true?

Comment: Presumably, your question is whether $f$ **has** an absolute minimum only if it is convex.  This is certainly not true.  We can state, however, that if a function is convex, then it has an absolute minimum.

Comment: In fact, any continuous function on a compact set has both an absolute minimum and maximum.

Comment: Two questions then:
1) What must be true for any f(x) to have a global minimizer? Or, similarly, how could any f(x) NOT have a global minimizer?

2) How could any f(x) have more than one global minimizer? Is that only when there are multiple "local" minimums that are equal and less than all other minimums?

Comment: @alan213123: Consider the functions $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^4-2x^3+x^2.$ Note that $f$ has no global minimum and that $g$ has global minima at $x=0$ *and* at $x=1.$

Comment: @CameronBuie I see what you're saying. So I know that there is going to be at least one global minimum because ||x|| approaches infinity, and must do so from somewhere below infinity. I'm not sure how to express this mathematically.